# SearchBox in Form using react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

Created a Modal having Form, and I want to add a place SearchBox.

All I need is the Name of the Place and Not the Map.

Using this Project - [react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/places/search-box)
I'm trying to use the above mentioned project and according to it.
I am able to get the "Customized Search Box".

How can I just use the searchbox and not the whole map.

And also it's messed up in zIndex.

[image]

The "**as**" written in the Placeholder box is transparent and 
search suggestions i.e "**ashley homestore**" are at the back of the box.

How to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple to switch to
[Google React Placeholder Autocomplete](https://kenny-hibino.github.io/react-places-autocomplete/)
by kenny-hibino